# error with store NSdate in coredata

Tags: ios, core-data, nsdate

I want to store the current date into the core data. The entity is called Emotions with several attributes(float) and a attribute named timeStamp(Date). Nothing is wrong with the float attributes. But when I tried to store date like this:

```
emotionAppDelegate * appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSManagedObjectContext *emotion =
[appDelegate managedObjectContext];
NSManagedObject *newEmotions;
newEmotions = [NSEntityDescription
              insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Emotions"
              inManagedObjectContext:emotion];
[newEmotions setValue:[NSData data] forKey:@"timeStamp"];
```

I got an error:

```
2012-11-25 21:03:09.130 silder[4634:c07] Unresolved error Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134100 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 134100.)" UserInfo=0x8174b20 {metadata={
NSPersistenceFrameworkVersion = 419;
NSStoreModelVersionHashes =     {
    Emotions = <c8b9e393 5624a477 dee1958e 19dd1209 acb67cd9 56daefea dbf8bfc9 daa8e34d>;
};
NSStoreModelVersionHashesVersion = 3;
NSStoreModelVersionIdentifiers =     (
    ""
);
NSStoreType = SQLite;
NSStoreUUID = "5CE10BB2-A77A-4E8B-AAE6-5973000DFADA";
"_NSAutoVacuumLevel" = 2;
```

}, reason=The model used to open the store is incompatible with the one used to create the store}, {
    metadata =     {
        NSPersistenceFrameworkVersion = 419;
        NSStoreModelVersionHashes =         {
            Emotions = ;
        };
        NSStoreModelVersionHashesVersion = 3;
        NSStoreModelVersionIdentifiers =         (
            ""
        );
        NSStoreType = SQLite;
        NSStoreUUID = "5CE10BB2-A77A-4E8B-AAE6-5973000DFADA";
        "_NSAutoVacuumLevel" = 2;
    };
    reason = "The model used to open the store is incompatible with the one used to create the store";
}

Can anyone help me? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

somehow you changed the database model, try to reset your simulator and run the application agian

Comment: Thank you! But I got an new error:Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unacceptable type of value for attribute: property = "timeStamp"; desired type = NSDate; given type = NSConcreteData; value = <>.'

Comment: better you set property type to NSDate

Comment: [newEmotions setValue:[NSData data] forKey:@"timeStamp"]; I think I create it as a NSDate..

Comment: you are using [NSData data] use [NSDate date]

Comment: So funny, happened to me as well. After hours of working NSData looks like NSDate :D